# Access data from regular expression with quantifiers

Tags: ruby, regex

When using Regular Expressions in ruby how do you get all data from a regular expression that uses quantifiers. For example I have the regex

```
/(\d+),(\d+): ([udrl])* (\d+.\d+,*)*/
```

which is suppose to match the lines

```
0,0: d 0.391538986557049
0,1: ur 63.1258159853081,3.14882640637611
```

My expression matches the lines however when I use $3 to access the string of letters it only returns the last letter, it is the same when using $4 to try and access the list of decimal numbers. How can I access each individual letter and decimal number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
([udrl])*
```

into

```
([udrl]*)
```

The first form makes $3 to match the last occurrence.
the second form makes $3 to match the string